# AJAX - Nested UpdatePanels. How to prevent inner from being updated?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a outer updatepanel that has a few buttons and a inner updatepanel within the outer one.

Both of them are set to updatemode=conditional. I would want the updates to happen independent of each other. However, when a button is clicked in the outer updatepanel, the inner updatepanel is updated as well.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do it with the structure you describe, since an update in the outer panel will cause the whole panel (including the inner one) to update. One solution would be to add another updatepanel so you end up with something like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="outer" ...>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="inner1" ...>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="inner2" ...>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

that way you can control each part independently